# How can I show a DialogFragment using compatibility package?

Tags: android, compatibility, android-fragments, fragment

I've tried to use DialogFragment on 3.0- devices, which not supports Fragment or DialogFragment by SDK level.

So, I decided to use Android compatibility library, which supports Fragment.
Then I created a DialogFragment class that extends **android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment**.

But.....When I tried to show my DialogFragment using DialogFragment.show(), I notified that show(FragmentManager, String) accepts first argument as **android.app.FragmentManager**, not **android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager**.

I think android.app.FragmentManager cannot be used in Android 3.0- devices, because it is not included in SDK.

Is there any way to show DialogFragment with Compatibility library? Am I have to use another way to show My DialogFragment with compatibility library?

Any help will be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 15):

The compatibility package is for those developing on Android versions prior to 3.0.

Both the [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) and the [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) classes exist in API level 11 (3.0)

In any Fragment or Activity you should be able to do the following to display a small (empty) dialog in the middle of the screen:

```
DialogFragment df = new DialogFragment();
df.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyDF");
```

Comment: Replace getFragmentManager with getSupportFragmentManager().

Answer (score 10):

`FragmentManager` and `DialogFragment` exists in the compat lib for sdk version 4 and upwards, make sure you import those ones.

User `getSupportFragmentManager()` to get your `FragmentManager` for the compat lib.

Show dialog as described in `DialogFragment` documentation passing compat lib version of `FragmentManager'.

Note that you can also treat the `DialogFragment` as a `Fragment` and 'show' it using `add(...)` or `replace(...)` as part of a transaction, i.e. you are not restricted to just using `show(...)`

Comment: What would the difference be between add() and show()?