# edit text in alert dialog

Tags: java, android, xml

i've this dialog

```
case DIALOGO_EDIT:

final EditText editText = new EditText(context);

builder.setView(editText);

builder.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {

    }
});

builder.setNegativeButton("Close", null);

break;
```

But when i rotate the device the dialog dismiss... How can i solve this problem and mantein the dialog during rotation? Or display the edit text at "full screen" like WhatsApp

Answer (score 0):

When the screen is rotated, the activity actually is restarted and killed, so you need to save and be able to restore the data using the lifecycle methods. Have a look here: [Saving Persistent State](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState)

You may want to have a look to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

The best way of avoid this problem is to use [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Create a new class extended to DialogFragment. Override `onCreateDialog` and return your old Dialog or an AlertDialog.

Them you can show it with `DialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, tag)`.

Here an example with the activity like listener:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public interface YesNoListener {
        void onYes();

        void onNo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (!(activity instanceof YesNoListener)) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement YesNoListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.dialog_my_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.dialog_my_message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ((YesNoListener) getActivity()).onYes();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ((YesNoListener) getActivity()).onNo();
                    }
                })
                .create();
    }
}
```

And in the Activity you call:

```
new MyDialogFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag"); // or getFragmentManager() in API 11+
```

This kind of questions already asked,and there are also solution for it, these three questions are matched with your problem (and they answered):

[Android Best way of avoid Dialogs to dismiss after a device rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11965154/842697)

[Android DialogFragment vs Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7977392/842697)

[How can I show a DialogFragment using compatibility package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6746978/842697)